# Angular 4 View not updating after model change

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, ng2-dragula

I have drag and drop option with a tree structure, but all the nodes are made siblings due to some functionalities, So that we can make any node as parent.

I am using Dragula [ng2-dragula](https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/) for drag and drop.

If I drag a parent, I need to move all the children along with the parent 
(Its enough to move the child after drop the parent).

HTML

```
<tbody [dragula]='"edit-tags-drag"' [dragulaModel]="structure" #tagsBag>
```

When I modify the structure array manually in ts file, the view is not updating.

TS File

```
constructor(public store: Store<any[]>,
          private dragulaService: DragulaService,
          private translate: TranslateService,
          private appRef: ApplicationRef,
          private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {};
ngOnInit () {
    this.dragulaService.dropModel.subscribe((item) => {
//Updating the structure
     }
}
```

I tried

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
this.ref.markForCheck();
this.appRef.tick();
setTimeout();
```

as well. 
If I am having separate button and binding click event, View is updating.
Any sort of help would be great.

Edit: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ELwbLmYE9vlPZdAyBvP6?p=preview) link added

Comment: Please provide plunker

Comment: @yurzui Plunker added

Comment: @BalajiPerumal How are you modifiying your array? We need to see the code.